# Guidelines for posting Apple-related questions on [[Ask Different]] versus [[Super User]]

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, superuser

There seems to be substantial overlap in the respective question domains of **Ask Different** and **Super User**, as the latter contains thousands of Apple-specific questions. What are the rules, guidelines, or etiquette for determining which site is more appropriate for a given Apple-related question?

(I gather that cross-posting is not allowed.)

Comment: _"I gather that cross-posting is not allowed"_ I well note that, though I believe this should be asked at Meta Super User.

Comment: Lots of sites have an overlap, just check Superusers help to  see what they support https://superuser.com/help/on-topic AFAIK the OS or brand is irreverent there. If your question fits they will take it, if not, go to Ask Different. Really it is up to you what site you prefer if it fits both.